# Отправка html письма с использованием Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Имеется такой вот шаблон на Smarty

```
<table width="100%" border="2" class="bordered">
    <tr><th style="text-align:center;"><b>ID заказа</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Контактное лицо</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Адрес доставки</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Способ доставки</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Контакты</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Сумма</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Дата заказа</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Дата доставки</b></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><b>Статус</b></th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.id}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.fio}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.countries}, {$order.city}{if !empty($order.adress)}, {$order.adress}{/if}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.delivery}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.email}<br/>{$order.telefon}</a></td>
        {math equation="x * y" x=$order.summa y=$setup.currency_exchange assign="currency"}
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$currency} {$setup.currency_symbol}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{$order.time|date_format:"d.m.o в H:i"}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">{if !empty($order.timedelivery)}, {$order.timedelivery|date_format:"d.m.o в H:i"}{/if}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="{$home}/profile/order/{$order.id}" title="Просмотреть заказ">
        {if $order.status == 1}<font color="green">принят</font>{/if}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

Таким способом не работает

```
//отправка письма о заказе пользователю
$order = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id`='".$fid."'"));
$smarty->assign('order',$order);
$template_mail = file_get_contents(SMARTY_TEMPLATE_LOAD.'/templates/template_mail/new_order.tpl'); // Открываем файл в режиме чтения
// инициализируем класс
$mailer = new phpmailer();
// Устанавливаем тему письма
$mailer->Subject = "Заказ товара на сайте ".$home;
//задаем e-mail админа
$mailer->From = $setup['emailadmin'];
$mailer->ContentType = 'text/html';
// Задаем тело письма
$mailer->Body = $template_mail;
// Добавляем адрес в список получателей
if($user['id'])
$mailer->AddAddress($user['email'], '');
else
$mailer->AddAddress($email, '');
$mailer->Send();
```

Как его отправить на e-mail пользователю?

Comment: По идее нужно скомпилировать шаблон и потом его использовать. Только что-то не пойму как)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.fetch.tpl